# Why is negative one (-1) elevated to the power of an even integer returning always the same result in Julia?

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I'm currently executing the following (very simple) code in Julia:

```
-1^2
```

But for some reason the result is always:

```
-1
```

Now, if I put in parenthesis, then the answer is correct. So I'm curious as to why this is happening. I'm running this on a Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Because 1 squared is 1, and minus that is minus 1?

Comment: This is just how it is. The order of operations places exponentiation before negation so -1^2 is the same as -(1^2)

Comment: If in doubt, you can call `Meta.@dump -1^2` or `Meta.show_sexpr(:(-1^2))` to see what it is thinking.

Comment: @mcabbott I didn't know that! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to order of operations. Exponentiation takes precedence over Subtraction, so you get -(1^n) which is always -1.